# Clone private GitHub repo AWS Sagemaker NB instance using AWS CloudFormation

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sagemaker

How do you set up a AWS Sagemaker Notebook instance, using CloudFormation, which is connected to one of your private GitHub repositories?

Note: I have added `GitHub oauth` to a `ssm` parameter (called github) before launching the stack.

So far I have tried to set up the aformentioned framework using `NotebookInstanceLifecycleConfig`.

This example shows how I am able to clone a public repository:

```
  FastaiNotebookInstanceLifecycleConfig:
    Type: "AWS::SageMaker::NotebookInstanceLifecycleConfig"
    Properties:
      NotebookInstanceLifecycleConfigName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-lifecycle-config
      OnStart:
        - Content: !Base64 |
            #!/bin/bash

            git clone https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-mlops-workshop.git /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/mlops_example
```

However, how can I customize `Lifecycleconfig` to clone a private repository instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this SageMaker feature for Git integration to clone your private repo: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-git-repo.html#nbi-git-create

Links to CloudFormation document for the related resources:

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sagemaker-coderepository.html

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sagemaker-notebookinstance.html

Jun

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to answer, specifically `Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.`.

Comment: Updated my answer based on vlizana@'s comments.